# Expected value via Darth Vader Rule on fuction

Tags: probability, expected-value

$$E(Max(0,X - d )) = \int_{d}^{\infty}1-F(X)dx $$
How can i prove this?
$$E(Max(0,X - d )) =E(g(X))= \int_{0}^{\infty}(P(g(X)>x) dx = \int_{0}^{d}(P(0>x) dx +\int_{d}^{\infty}(P(X - d > x) dx  $$
But it is clearly wrong and i dont know why.

Comment: Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.

Comment: You are confusing $X$ with $x$ when you split the integral.

Comment: @geetha290krm Can you clarify what I'm wrong?

Comment: $\int_{0}^{\infty}P\left(\max\left\{ 0,X-d\right\} >x\right)dx=\int_{0}^{\infty}P\left(X-d>x\right)dx$
because for positive $x$: $$\max\left\{ 0,X-d\right\} >x\iff X-d>x$$

Answer (score 1):

$Y:=\max(0,X-d)$ is a positive random variable and for every positive random variable we have:$$\mathbb EY=\int_0^{\infty}P(Y>y)dy$$

Note that $\{Y>y\}=\{X>d+y\}$ for every $y>0$ so that we can substitute: $$P(Y>y)=P(X>d+y)=1-F_X(d+y)$$leading to:$$\mathbb EY=\int_0^{\infty}1-F_X(d+y)dy=\int_d^{\infty}1-F_X(x)dx$$